# Java api to create visualization in kibana 6

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, java

I'm new to elastic suit and I want to know if there is any way I can create visualization in kibana from java api?

To be more specific:I have a chatbot  where I define different parameters from user sentences.
When user submit requests, in background (java code) I want to create visualization using the provided parameters.
Then get the iframe and embed it on to the chatbot for user.
Any pointers to this will be very helpful.

Thanks,
Costi P.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no dedicated Java API for defining visualizations in kibana.

You can however post a visualization to the kibana index.
See details here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/building-kibana-dashboard-dynamically/33713

There is also this: 
* https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-create-visualization-on-the-fly-using-a-script/31255
* https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-dynamically-create-kibana-dashboard-in-5-0/74259